# localStorage eventListener is not called

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I added an eventListener to the window DOM-Object and want to keep track of the changes made to localStorage.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script language="JavaScript"><!-- 
        window.addEventListener('storage', storageEventHandler, false);
        function storageEventHandler(evt){
            console.log("oldValue: " + evt.oldValue );
            console.log("storage event called key: " + evt.key );
            console.log("newValue: " + evt.newValue );

        }
        $(document).ready(function(event) {
            $('#link1').click(function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                localStorage.setItem('page', 2000);
                console.log(localStorage.getItem('page'));
            });
            $('#link2').click(function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                localStorage.setItem('page', 998);
                console.log(localStorage.getItem('page'));

            });

         });
    </script>
</head>
</html>
```

Somehow the storageEventHandler is never called even though the localStorage value is changed when I click link1 or link2.
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: whether or not the `storage` event gets fired, depends on the browser.

Comment: That's correct, see e.g. http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=48159.

Comment: in react i used window.dispatchEvent(new Event("storage")) after changing storage. this will call listeners manually

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Some browsers don't support the storage event, and most of the browsers that do support it will only call it **when the storage is changed by a different window/tab**. So, open your page up in two windows. Click the links in one window and you will probably see the event in the other.

The assumption is that your page will already know all interactions with localStorage in its own window and only needs notification when a different window changes things. This, of course, is a foolish assumption. But, localStorage is a new thing. Hopefully, they'll eventually figure it all out.

Comment: unfortunately, the aforementioned time "eventually" hasn't come yet :(

Comment: Sadly, that's true. I hope to make time to revisit this eventually. I have some wild hack ideas for working around some of these things. I just don't have much time for such experiments these days.

Comment: http://html5demos.com/storage-events

Comment: 7 years later and this still doesn't work as one would assume.

Comment: Not sure why but the "eventually" part hasn't been fixed yet. IMO, that could have been a very useful feature.

Comment: @BML91 Make that ten years

Answer (score 32):

The `storage` event handler will only affect other windows. Whenever something changes in one window inside `localStorage` all the other windows are notified about it and if any action needs to be taken it can be achieved by a handler function listening to the `storage` event.

For same window you have to manually call the `storageEventHandler` function after `localStorage.setItem()` is called to achieve the same behaviour in the same window.

Comment: That's the answer. Thanks.

Comment: note: _IE10 : The storage event is fired even on the originating document where it occurred._ [resource](https://caniuse.com/#search=localstorage)

Comment: can U provide an example, im lost with your answer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/storage_event