# How to subscribe to an observable from a SessionStorage

Tags: angular, session-storage

In an Angular component (FirstComponent), I call a service, from which I get an object as a response.I store the response in the browser in a  "sessionStorage".

```js
sessionStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(response));
```

Now, in another component (SecondComponent), I get the "sessionStorage", and paint the results into a Datagrid from an internal component library.

```js
let response = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("data"));
```

When calling a component library method with which you can load the Datagrid columns, it gives me the following error:

Concrete line error:

```
columnsOptions[5].visible = false

core.js:6210 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '5')
    at TasksContainerComponent.addView (tasks-container.component.ts:144:21)
    at TasksContainerComponent.getScheduleTasks (tasks-container.component.ts:118:16)
    at SafeSubscriber._next (tasks-container.component.ts:52:12)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:183:1)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:122:1)
    at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:72:1)
    at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49:1)
    at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:35:1)
    at MapSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49:1)
    at BehaviorSubject._subscribe (BehaviorSubject.js:14:1)
```

I get the response from the service of the first component correctly in the second component with "SessionStorage", but it gives me the indicated error. The funny thing is that, if I call the same service of the first component in the second component without using "SessionStorage", I get returns the same response, and everything works perfectly.

It's like I have to create a "sessionStorage" observable and subscribe to load the data correctly, but so far I haven't figured out how to do that.

To optimize, I would like to call the service only once, since in both components I need the same response to paint the data.

This is the second component's OnInit event and this is the error it shows me when I use "SessionStorage", the "columnsOptions" constant is not defined, however if I don't use "SessionStorage" and launch the "columnsOptions" service call, it has the value I need and it works fine.

The objective is to paint the Datagrid with the object stored in "SessionStorage", but I hide a column of the Datagrid in case it has "0" errors, if the "hasErrors" parameter contains 0, it is that I haven't errors and I must hide the last Datagrid column, this is the code that fails exclusively when I try to hide the column:

```js
const columnsOptions: DatagridColumnOptions[] = this.dg.columns?.map(column => ({
  column: column,
  visible: true,
  level: 0,
}));

if (hasErrors === 0) { 
  columnsOptions[5].visible = false;
}
```

The error is on this line:

```js
columnsOptions[5].visible = false;
```

But it is because:

```js
columnsOptions = undefined;
```

What I can do?

Comment: Can you be a bit more descriptive on what you want done, I'm confused.
The error `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '5')` just means that `columnsOptions` is undefined at the time you are calling it

Comment: I have added more information in the question, hope it helps.

Comment: Are you trying to share data through 'sessionStorage'?

Comment: Exactly with "sessionStorage" but it doesn't work, however calling the service again working ok

Comment: Don't use sessionStorage or localStorage to share data between component. You can only store text within these storages. Don't expect to storage an observable in it and be able to subscribe to it. Instead create the observable in your service. Subscribe to it from both components, and emit new values triggered by a function from your first component.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the advice, I will try to do it based on your indications

Comment: In the end, I'm passing the observable through a service, without using "SessionStorage" but I still have the same problem :(

Comment: You can subscribe to your sessionstorage as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60235005/using-angular-observable-to-subscribe-to-session-storage-key). But I agree it is a bad practice to do so to communicate between components.
We are missing some code to be able to help you. If you create a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) with a minimal reproduction and @ me in a comment, I'll gladly take a look at it.

Comment: Just before of define the variable "columnsOptions" I put: "this.ref.detectChanges();" and it worked ok, thanks for the offer @H3AR7B3A7