# How to instantly update state when any changes into the localStorage in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage, next.js

How to update cart page data instantly when any changes in the `localStorage` `myCart` array? Here is my code below

```
const [cart, setCart] = React.useState([])

React.useEffect(() => {
    setCart(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myCart')) || [])
}, [])
```

the `cart` is updated when the page reloads but not when new item adds or updates any existing items!

How can I achieve that, which is `cart` update instantly if any changes into 'localStorage`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: so how `localStorage` changes are made?

Comment: why linking the state with window storage?

Comment: @Apostolos Adding a new item to the cart or updating quantity.

Comment: Can you show the function which use to add items to cart ?

Answer (score 15):

You can add an [eventlistener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/storage_event) to the `localstorage` event

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    
window.addEventListener('storage', () => {
  // When local storage changes, dump the list to
  // the console.
   setCart(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myCart')) || [])   
});

   
}, [])
```

> The storage event of the Window interface fires when a storage area
> (localStorage) has been modified.The storage event is only triggered when a window other than itself makes the changes.

.

Comment: didn't know that event actually. useful answer :)

Comment: I think there's more to this.  Isn't the handler only called when a _different_ window updates localStorage?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/6846158/3084820

Comment: Yeah it is ,but it attaches an event listener to the localstorage ,no matter how the local storage is updated .It works absolutely :)

Comment: @Shubh that is not working, see the code [Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ln2SeHr35iJECws7X5eGly20fI7XkQCZ/view?usp=sharing) but it only shows "ok"

Comment: Did you try changing the localstorage as well ??@jesica

Comment: I copied your code and tested it by updating localStorage from the console and a button click. It does not work at all. The event listener is never called. I am using Google Chrome Version 91.0.4472.124

Comment: Please read the mozilla link again -Note: `This won't work on the same page that is making the changes — it is really a way for other pages on the domain using the storage to sync any changes that are made. Pages on other domains can't access the same storage objects.`@mnagdev

Comment: how to maintain login and logout state globally , when localstorage is used to save login and logout state

Comment: In order for this to work, you need to do `window.dispatchEvent(new Event('storage'))` whereever changes to localStorage is happening.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a better way to handle the situation. This is how I handle a situation like this.

In you component,

```
const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);

React.useEffect(() => {
    async function init() {
      const data = await localStorage.getItem('myCart'); 
      setCart(JSON.parse(data));
    }
    init();
}, [])
```

> the cart is updated when the page reloads but not when new item adds
> or updates any existing items!
>
> How can I achieve that, which is cart update instantly if any changes
> into 'localStorage`?

When you add items, let's assume you have a method `addItem()`

```
async function addItem(item) {
  // Do not update local-storage, instead update state
  await setState(cart => cart.push(item));
}
```

Now add another `useEffect()`;

```
useEffect(() => {
 localstorage.setItem('myCart', cart);
}, [cart])
```

Now when cart state change it will save to the localstorage

`addEventListener` on storage is not a good thing. Everytime storage change, in you code, you have to getItems and parsed it which takes some milliseconds to complete, which cause to slow down the UI update.

In react,

1. first load data from `localstorage` / `database` and initialize the state.
2. Then update the state in the code as you want.
3. Then listen on state changes to do any task ( In this case save to localstorage )

If your `addItem()` function is a child of the above component ( cart component ), then you can pass the `setItem` funtion as a prop / or you can use contex API or else use Redux

UPDATE

If `addCart` is another component

1. if the component that has `addCart` function is a child component of `cart` component, use `props` - https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html
2. if the component that has `addCart` function is NOT a child component of `cart` component, use context api to communicate between components - https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html
3. if you want to manage your data in clean & better way, use https://redux.js.org/

According to the use case, I assume your `addItem` function declared in a `Product` component..

I recommend you to use Redux to handle the situation.

**UPDATE**

As @Matt Morgan said in comment section, using context API is better for the situation.

But if your application is a big one ( I assumed that you are building an e-commerce system ) it may be better to use a state management system like Redux. Just for this case, context API will be enough

Comment: What if `addToCart` function in different component and for me that is. How can achieve that if separate component?

Comment: You can use `props` , `context` or `redux`. I have added some links to the answer

Comment: Redux is probably overkill for this situation.  Using context is probably the most idiomatic and lightweight way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I followed the answer given by `@Shubh` above.

It works when an existing value is deleted from the local storage or when another window in the same browser updates a value being used in the local storage.
It does not work when, let's say, clicking on a button in the same window updates the local storage.

The below code handles that as well. It might look a bit redundant, but it works:

```
        const [loggedInName, setLoggedInName] = useState(null);
        
        useEffect(() => {
            setLoggedInName(localStorage.getItem('name') || null)
            window.addEventListener('storage', storageEventHandler, false);
        }, []);
        
        function storageEventHandler() {
            console.log("hi from storageEventHandler")
            setLoggedInName(localStorage.getItem('name') || null)
        }
    
        function testFunc() {
        localStorage.setItem("name", "mayur1234");
        storageEventHandler();
    }



return(
<div>
  <div onClick={testFunc}>TEST ME</div>
</div>
)
```

**Edit:**

I also found a bad hack to do this using a hidden button in one component, clicking which would fetch the value from localStorage and set it in the current component.

This hidden button can be given an id and be called from any other component using plain JS

eg: `document.getElementById("hiddenBtn").click()`

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/69222203/9977815 for details

Answer (score 0):

We can get live update using useEffect in the following way

```
   React.useEffect(() => {
        const handleExceptionData = () => {
            setExceptions(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('exp')).data)
        }
        window.addEventListener('storage', handleExceptionData)
        return function cleanup() {
            window.removeEventListener('storage', handleExceptionData)
        }
    }, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not intended to be an exact answer to the OP. But I needed a methed to update the State (from local storage) when the user changes tabs, because the useEffect was not triggered in the second tab, and therefore the State was outdated.

```
  window.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function() {
      setCart(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myCart')))
  })
```

This adds a listener which is triggered when the visibility changes, which then pulls the data from local storage and assigns it to the State.

In my application, triggering on a "storage" event listener resulted in this running far too many times, while this gets triggered less (but still when needed) - when the user changes tabs.

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question but still seems popular so for anyone viewing now, since I'm not sure it's possible to trigger a real-time update from window storage and have it be reliable, I would suggest a reducer hook to solve the problem (you can update storage via the reducer but it would likely be redundant). This is a basic version of the useCart hook I used with useReducer to keep the cart state updated (updates in real-time when quantity changes as well).

```
import React, { useReducer, useContext, createContext, useCallback} from 'react';

const CartContext = createContext(); 

export function cartReducer(cartState, action) {  
    
    switch (action.type) { 
        case 'addToCart':
            const newItem = action.payload;
            const isExisting = cartState.find( item => (item.serviceid === newItem.serviceid));
            if(isExisting){
                return cartState.map( currItem => (currItem.serviceid === newItem.serviceid) ? 
                    {...newItem, quantity: currItem.quantity + 1}
                    : currItem
            )};
            return [...cartState, {...newItem}]
        
        case 'removeFromCart':
                const itemToRemove = action.payload;
                const existingCartItem = cartState.find(
                    cartItem => cartItem.serviceid === itemToRemove.serviceid
                );
                if(existingCartItem){
                    return cartState.map(cartItem =>
                        (cartItem.serviceid === itemToRemove.serviceid && cartItem.quantity > 0) ? 
                        {...cartItem, quantity: cartItem.quantity - 1}
                        : cartItem
                )}
            return [...cartState, action.payload]    
        
        case 'emptyCart':
        return []

        default:
            throw new Error();
        }
}
export const CartProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(cartReducer, []);
    return <CartContext.Provider value={{ state, dispatch }}>{children}</CartContext.Provider>;
};

export const useCart = () => {
    const {state, dispatch} = useContext(CartContext);

    const addToCart = useCallback((payload) => {
        dispatch({type: 'addToCart', payload});
    }, [dispatch, state]);
    
    const removeFromCart = useCallback((payload) => {
        dispatch({type: 'removeFromCart', payload});
    }, [dispatch, state]);

    const emptyCart = useCallback((payload) => {
        dispatch({type: 'emptyCart', payload});
    }, [dispatch]); 
        
    return {
        cart: state,
        addToCart,
        removeFromCart,
        emptyCart,
    }
}
```

Then all you need to do is either add it to your provider component (if you have a lot of providers) or just wrap your app in the CartProvider directly.

```
import React from "react";
import { AuthProvider } from "./hooks/useAuth";
import { CartProvider } from "./hooks/useCart";
import { PaymentProvider } from "./paymentGateway/gatewayHooks/usePayment.js";
import { StoreProvider } from "./store/StoreProvider";
import { MuiPickersUtilsProvider } from "@material-ui/pickers";
import DateFnsUtils from "@date-io/date-fns";

export function AppProvider({ children }) {
return (
    <AuthProvider>
        <StoreProvider>
            <CartProvider>
            <PaymentProvider>
                <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
                    {children}
                </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
            </PaymentProvider>
            </CartProvider>
        </StoreProvider>
    </AuthProvider>
);
}
```

Your main App component would look something like this when you're done and you can also now access the cart state from any other child in your app regardless of how deep it may be buried.

```
    export default function App() {
        
        return (
            <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
                    <CssBaseline />
                        <BrowserRouter>
                            <AppProvider>
                                <AppLayout />
                            </AppProvider>
                        </BrowserRouter>
                </LocalizationProvider>
            </ThemeProvider>
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use react context provider together with local storage

```
type Foo = {
    bar: string
}

const FooEmpty = {
    bar: ""
}
const FOO_STORAGE_ITEM = "__foo";

export const removeFooStorage = () => {
    localStorage.removeItem(FOO_STORAGE_ITEM);
};

export const getFooStorage = (): Foo => {
    const fromStorage = localStorage.getItem(FOO_STORAGE_ITEM);
    return fromStorage ? JSON.parse(fromStorage) : FooEmpty;
};

export const setFooStorage = (
    foo: Foo
) => {
    localStorage.setItem(
        FOO_STORAGE_ITEM,
        JSON.stringify(foo)
    );
};

export const FooContext = React.createContext({
    foo: FooEmpty,
    setFoo: (value: Foo) => {},
});
```

Then wrap the components that need the storage item into context

```
const MyComponent = () => {
    // Init foo state from storage
    const [fooState, setFooState] = useState(
            getFooStorage()
        );

    // Every time when context state update, update also storage item
    useEffect(() => {
        setFooStorage(fooState);
    }, [fooState]);


    // Wrap all foo state consumer components in Foo context provider
    <FooContext.Provider 
        value={{
            foo: fooState
            setFoo: setFooState
        }}
    >
         // In foo consumer component, call useContext(FooContext) to read or update foo states
         <FooConsumerComponent/>
    </FooContext.Provider>

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hook I made for this.
Inspired by https://michalkotowski.pl/writings/how-to-refresh-a-react-component-when-local-storage-has-changed

```
// Inspired by https://michalkotowski.pl/writings/how-to-refresh-a-react-component-when-local-storage-has-changed
const useLocalStorage = <T extends object>(key: string) => {
    const [storage, _setStorage] = useState<T>({} as unknown as T);
    useEffect(() => {
        const handleStorage = () => {
            _setStorage(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key) ?? '{}'));
        };

        window.addEventListener('storage', handleStorage);
        return () => window.removeEventListener('storage', handleStorage);
    }, []);
    const setStorage = (data: unknown) => {
        localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(data));
        window.dispatchEvent(new Event('storage'));
    };
    return [storage, setStorage];
};

export default useLocalStorage;
```