# how to maintain login and logout state globally and reflect the changes, when localstorage is used to save login and logout state globally in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have a function in `AuthAPI.js`

and it has the following code

```js
const isLoggedIn = () => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
  return token ? true : false;
};
```

i want to show `login` and `logout` navbar item conditionally, when user logouts and logins

`Navlink.js` code ->

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

import { isLoggedIn } from "../APIHandler/AuthAPI";

import styles from "./NavLinks.module.css";

export default function NavLinks() {
  const [isLoggedInState, setIsLoggedInState] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function init() {
      const token = await localStorage.getItem("token");
      console.log({ token });
      token ? setIsLoggedInState(true) : setIsLoggedInState(false);
    }
    init();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log({ isLoggedInState });
    if (isLoggedInState == false) {
      localStorage.removeItem("token");
    }
  }, [localStorage]);

  const handleLogout = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("called handle logout");
    // localStorage.removeItem("token");
    setIsLoggedInState(false);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <li className={styles.main_nav__item}>
        <NavLink to="/">HOME</NavLink>
      </li>

      <li className={styles.main_nav__item}>
        <NavLink to="/blogs">BLOGS</NavLink>
      </li>
      {!isLoggedInState && (
        <li className={styles.main_nav__item}>
          <NavLink to="/login">LOGIN</NavLink>
        </li>
      )}
      {isLoggedInState && (
        <li className={styles.main_nav__item}>
          <button onClick={handleLogout} className={styles.logout}>
            LOGOUT
          </button>
        </li>
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

- here ,when user clicks on logout , the token is being removed, but the component is not loaded to reflect the changes,
- how do I reflect the changes in navlink ,when user clicks on logout, it is possible if I use a state variable, but I am using local storage to tell whether user is logged in or not.
- I have tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62896954/how-to-instantly-update-state-when-any-changes-into-the-localstorage-in-react-js)
- but it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

I won't go into the design/best practices. But this should give you some idea how to achieve what you are aiming for.

This is based on my own encounter with a login/logout problem that I addressed in the past.
Sharing so that this might help in some way. The steps here are somewhat generic so that anyone can relate to his/her scenario. :

You would need context and hooks.

You can do something like this in your App.js file :

```
export const AuthContext = React.createContext();

const initialState = {
    isAuthenticated: <<your logic here where you decide based on local storage sth like localStorage.getItem(<<sth based on your usecase>>) >>? true : false,
    user: null,
    token: null,
};
```

Then in the same **App.js** use a reducer like this:

```
const reducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "LOGIN":
            // if (action.remember) {
            localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(action.payload));
            // }
            return {
                ...state,
                isAuthenticated: true,
                user: action.payload,
            };
        case "LOGOUT":
            window.localStorage.clear();
            return {
                ...state,
                isAuthenticated: false,
                user: null,
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

Inside your **App** function :

```
function App() {
    const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, initialState);

    useEffect(() => {
        return () => {
        };
    }, [state.isAuthenticated]);
```

Wrap the entire content of return inside **AuthContext.Provider** :

```
return (
<AuthContext.Provider value={{state, dispatch}}>

//here sits your layout/BrowserRouter and other things that you typically would expect.

</AuthContext.Provider>
);
```

#### Setting the LOGIN or LOGOUT state for our dispatch

You can set the state to **LOGIN** or **LOGOUT** wherever you are handling the authentication.

For your case looks liek you are doing this inside **AuthAPI.js**.

So for **LOGIN** call the **dispatch** method.

Below is a typical example of using in a then block of an axios or similar rest call. But as said earlier you can call this anywhere where you are doing post authentication setup.  for your case it can be inside of your **isLoggedIn** function :

```
dispatch({
          type: "LOGIN",
          payload: res.data,
          remember: rememberMe,
        });
```

Similarly for **LOGOUT**, sth like calling the dispatch method on click of logout button:

```
onClick={() =>
          dispatch({
            type: "LOGOUT",
          })
        }
```

#### Now that we have the setup ready, how to use all of this in our components ??

Try to relate below with your **Navlink.js** component. But this would work for any other components too.

And then you can all the above in any other component(like your **Navlink.js** component) by just importing the **AuthContext** from App:

```
import { AuthContext } from "../App";
```

then get hold of the state and dispatch method :

```
  const { dispatch } = React.useContext(AuthContext);
  const { state } = React.useContext(AuthContext);
```

then check the login state by sth like :

```
  const [loginStatus, setLoginStatus] = useState(state.isAuthenticated);
```

Then based on the state, conditionally render components, sth like below inside your return statement:

```
return (

    <>
       <div>
       <<your other components here>>
       </div>

        {!state.isAuthenticated ? (
                  <Button
                    onClick={showLoginModalWindow}
                    icon={<FIIcons.FiLogIn />}
                  >
                    Login
                  </Button>
                ) : ( <div> ...someother component...</div>)}
    <>

);
```

I am really not an expert react developer. So constructive feedback are always welcome. Still learning and trying to help with whatever little I know.

**EDIT 1 : START**

For your specific use case, using ternary operator this would be :

```
return (
    <>
      <li className={styles.main_nav__item}>
        <NavLink to="/">HOME</NavLink>
      </li>

      <li className={styles.main_nav__item}>
        <NavLink to="/blogs">BLOGS</NavLink>
      </li>


      {!state.isAuthenticated ? (
        <li className={styles.main_nav__item}>
          <NavLink to="/login">LOGIN</NavLink>
        </li>
      ) : (
        <li className={styles.main_nav__item}>
          <button onClick={handleLogout} className={styles.logout}>
            LOGOUT
          </button>
        </li>
      )}
    </>
  );
```

**EDIT 1 : END**

Comment: i will try this with redux, bu  how will you make the login status get reflected on the navLink? will it get reflected? please try to add the logic for navLink.js too,

Comment: Added that. Let me know if that works for you. I'll also try to add some more edits to help you relate more with your Navbar component. Also, whatever I posted doesn't require reduce or any third party state management library. React Hooks are all we need here.

Comment: i will try this with redux and let you know

Comment: Sure. There is a typo in my earlier comment though. My bad. Fourth sentence should read "whatever I posted doesn't require Redux ", I mistakenly typed reduce.

Comment: yes ,it doesnt ,but i prefer redux instead of context api , it is very easy for me

Comment: thankyou , your idea worked , even though i used redux

Comment: Glad it worked.